# How to pass structure by reference in C?

Tags: c, struct

I have a structure that I need to use for two diferent variables (firstVar & secondVar).
I don't want to use vectors , just  2 plain structures. 
Since I don't want to duplicate the code that takes the user input, I would like to create an action that I call both for (firstVar and secondVar)

I would like to be able to pass the structure to the action by reference.
Here is my code, I still can not figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct {
    int id;
    float length;
} tMystruct;
tMystruct firstVar;
tMystruct secondVar;

void readStructs(tMystruct *theVar)
{
    scanf("%d",theVar.id);
    scanf("%f",theVar.length);
}

int main(void)
{
    readStructs(&firstVar);
    readStructs(&secondVar);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I still can not figure out what I am doing wrong" Please state what is the problem with this code. For programs that don't compile please post the full error message. For programs that compile post the expected behavior and the behavior you observe.

Comment: It seems you need to go back to your text-book, tutorial or class-notes to see how to access member variables of a *pointer to structure*.

Comment: both gcc and clang give very descriptive error messages in your case. Furthermore both of them give you the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problem,

```
void readStructs(tMystruct *theVar)
{
scanf("%d",theVar.id); //<------problem 
scanf("%f",theVar.length); //<------problem 
}
```

You should access Structure pointer member using `->` operator and also you're missing `&` that will eventually cause a segmentation fault.

Here is the modified code,

```
void readStructs(tMystruct *theVar)
{
scanf("%d",&theVar->id);
scanf("%f",&theVar->length);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind, in C, there really isn't *pass by reference*, you generally pass by value. This is subtle, but important distinction. consider this:

```
void func_a(int *a) {
    a = 0;
}

int main() {
    int value = 5;
    func_a(&value);

    return 0;
}
```

We see here that we set `a = 0;` However this has no impact on the actual value, you're just changing to where it points in the local function scope. If we wanted to actually change the value of `a` we'd have to dereference it.

```
*a = 0;
```

In languages such as C++ and C# there are language constructs to pass by reference, but in C you can only pass by value.

As for your code a simple fix is:

```
void readStructs(tMystruct *theVar)
{
    scanf("%d", &theVar->id);
    scanf("%f", &theVar->length);
}
```

Your function accepts a pointer to `tMystruct` as it's first argument, so we can use the arrow operator `->` and access the value and then take it's address and pass it to `scanf`. This is equivlaent to

```
void readStructs(tMystruct *theVar)
{
    scanf("%d", &((*theVar).id));
    scanf("%f", &((*theVar).length));
}
```

Comment: "There is no pass by reference in C" is an incorrect dogma inherited from confused C++ programmers. It is trivial to prove it wrong: `void func (int by_reference [1]);`, `void func (void by_reference (void));`.

Comment: @Lundin: I suggest instead citing the C11 standard for "pass by reference"

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch The term "pass by reference" is larger than C and older than C. It means: pass an address instead of the copy of the variable. The term was used that way before C was even invented. It is true that C has no formal term called "reference".  It also has no term called "programming", so by that same flawed logic there is no such thing as C programming.

Comment: I know that, but OP's question is about C.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Which is a language that allows you to pass anything by reference. Either explicitly, by passing a the value of pointer to the object, or implicitly in case of passing arrays or functions as in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You are passing them in as reference just fine.</strike>
As has been pointed out, all passing in C is by value only; the called function receives always a **copy** of whatever you pass in. In order to access the actual value outside of the function, you need it's address + type info, which in C is achieved by passing a pointer. And regarding that, there is nothing wrong in your code apart from the scanf calls, and you achieve what you expressed in everyday English:

> I would like to be able to pass the structure to the action by reference.

Now on to answer the question you actually asked:

You cannot use the dot notation on a struct that you only have a pointer to. Also, scanf wants the address of the variable it is going to write to.

```
void readStructs(tMystruct *theVar)
{
   scanf("%d",&theVar->id);
   scanf("%f",&theVar->length);
}
```

Comment: There is no passing by reference in C.

Comment: QJabberwocky: True, which is the reason I wrote "**as** reference". Of course, technically it is a pointer...

Comment: "as reference" is still the wrong term. He is just passing a pointer. The downvote is not mine btw.

Comment: A little bit up Lundin got it right, IMHO. The whole concept of passing an address rather than the actual value has been described  as "passing by reference" for more than half a century. As C does not have references, there should be no confusion about what is meant. Still, I will reword my answer so people from C++ land won't be offended.

Comment: @GermanNerd The issue comes up as languages add _pass by reference_ features which need to be distinguished from the _pass by value_. C doesn't have these features besides perhaps what Lundin mentioned with the weirdness of C arrays (which is a whole other topic) they can be referency but this behavior decays easily.

Comment: @Jacob I agree; one could say that languages like C++ 'hijacked' human language use to represent very specific programming language constructs. But even so, what is a C++ reference but a (castrated) pointer in disguise?