# print id card information using two different function and should be called in main function

Tags: c, function, struct, card

I want to print the id card using two different functions one for information from the user and the second function should display the information and should be called in the main function. please point out the mistake I am doing as it is not printing the proper value.

```
struct card
{
    char name[20];
    int clas;
    char section[20];
    int roll;
};

void info(struct card id)
{
    printf("\n Name: ");
    scanf(" %s", &id.name);
    printf("\nClass: ");
    scanf(" %d", &id.clas);
    printf("\nSection: ");
    scanf(" %s", &id.section);
    printf("\nRoll: ");
    scanf(" %d", &id.roll);
}

void displaydata(struct card id)
{
    printf("\nName: %s", id.name);
    printf("\nClass: %d", id.clas);
    printf("\nSection: %s", id.section);
    printf("\nRoll: %d", id.roll);
}

int main()
{
    struct card id2[4];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        info(id2[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("------");
        printf("student: %d", i + 1);

        displaydata(id2[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void info(struct card id)` is passing the struct by value which makes a copy. The function changes the data in the copy which is discarded when the function ends. You probably want to pass a pointer instead.

Comment: Please pay attention to [code formatting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). Edit your question to fix that.

Comment: The functions `info` and `displaydata` should take a `struct card*` as argument, not the structure itself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097276/how-to-pass-structure-by-reference-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code modified to use a pointer for the two functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct card
{
    char name[20];
    int clas;
    char section[20];
    int roll;
};

void info(struct card *id)
{
    printf("\n Name: ");
    scanf(" %s", &id->name);
    printf("\nClass: ");
    scanf(" %d", &id->clas);
    printf("\nSection: ");
    scanf(" %s", &id->section);
    printf("\nRoll: ");
    scanf(" %d", &id->roll);
}

void displaydata(struct card *id)
{
    printf("\nName: %s", id->name);
    printf("\nClass: %d", id->clas);
    printf("\nSection: %s", id->section);
    printf("\nRoll: %d", id->roll);
}

int main()
{
    struct card id2[4];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(id2) / sizeof(id2[0])); i++)
    {
        info(&id2[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < (sizeof(id2) / sizeof(id2[0])); i++)
    {
        printf("------");
        printf("student: %d", i + 1);

        displaydata(&id2[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I used `sizeof` to get the number of elements in the `id2` array. This is much better than a *magic* number that the reader cannot easily find the signification.

Also you should check if `scanf` is successful. For example:

```
if (scanf(" %s", &id->name) != 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Name not correctly input\n");
    // more code to handle the error, as needed
}
```

Comment: , it was really helpfull.